# Pythonic way to store/record agent-specific values in agent-based models?

Tags: python, agent-based-modeling

I want to keep track of agent-specific variables and I'm not sure about the pythonic way to do it.

For example, I have 400 households which receive and spend money over time. Each household as a unique ID, by which the household-specific variables (income, consumption) should be callable and mutable. I have to keep track of the specific variables because the actual agent decisions depends on decisions in the past (spending in time-step before for example).

So for one variable you could create 400 lists (by typing them? No way), or you could create a numpy array with 400 columns (rows = values in time-step t) and the column index corresponds with the household ID, or you could... And of course the agent-specific variables should be accesable for math operations, like sum or mean.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: I'd go with numpy, a dictionary-inherited class or just a plain SQL database to store large number of values. The class could easily store and track changes in variables and keep a history within itself. Inheriting a variable type and replace the built-in functions to just add the "track changes" operations wouldn't be to much fuzz.

Comment: It looks like you might want to explore using python-pandas.  You could read in the household data from say CSVs as DataFrames and manipulate that into most python native data objects that you care about.